# Installing to SDCARD from Android Market

Tags: android, sd-card

My application is programmed to be installed in SDCARD, i.e, following the information here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/apps-on-sd-card-details.html

I set "android:installLocation" to "preferExternal" inside the manifest tag. My build target is API 8, and my minSdkVersion=3. It works when I directly install the application into my HTC Desire (Android 2.2) with Eclipse. The application is saved into the SDCARD, and I can move to and from the internal memory.

However, when I download it from Android Market, the application is saved in the internal memory and I can't move it into the SDCARD. I am using the same device. Why is that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here

[Installing android app on sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035495/installing-android-app-on-sdcard)

If your app is copy-protected in your android developer console the sdcard installing will not work