# Installing android app on sdcard

Tags: android, sd-card

I developed an app which can install on sdcard or in mobile internal memory.
I used **`android:installLocation`** attribute set to **`"auto"`**.

Now the problem I am facing is when I run app on device then it shows me move to sdcard button enabled but when I uploaded the app to market and installed it from market then move to sdcard button is not enabled.

Any Idea where I am lagging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your app is not `copy-protected`:

> The Application Info screen now has either a “move to SD card” or
>   “move to phone” button, but this is often disabled. Copy-protected
>   apps and updates to system apps can’t be moved to the SD card, nor can
>   those which are don’t specify that they work on the SD card.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/apps-on-sd-card-details.html

Comment: any solution in 2018?